# Django massmailer - TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to setup up the django massmailer app for use in my project. However, several templates seem to be missing. For instance, from the admin page, some (but not all) models give an error when I click on them. 
Any suggestions on how to fix or debug the issue would be much appreciated. Not sure if this an issue with the app or my setup.

The error:

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/massmailer/template/
```

and the traceback finishes with:

```
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: reversion/change_list.html
```

Comment: please describe the error you get and most probably your own code aroundthe massmailer (eg. which version you are using, ...)

Comment: Using massmailer 0.6, and followed the instructions at https://github.com/prologin/django-massmailer. There's none of my own code interacting with this app at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it - I had not properly included all the massmailer dependencies.